# Logstash plugin development

Tags: ruby, logstash, jruby

I'm trying to develop an input plugin for logstash.

i've used this tutorial

http://blog.eagerelk.com/how-to-write-a-logstash-plugin/

the problem that i've had when i tried to install "bundle" using "bundle install"

*- this is the error message*

**Your Ruby engine is ruby, but your Gemfile specified jruby**

*- Gemfile:*

**source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '2.3.1'
gemspec**

*- ruby -v :*

**ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin16]**

*- jruby -v :*

**jruby 9.1.8.0 (2.3.1) 2017-03-06 90fc7ab Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14 on 1.8.0_92-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]**

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using `rvm` or `rbenv` in your project?

Comment: I'm using rbenv

Comment: And have you created the `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files appropriately? Looks like your bundler is trying to use the system's default Ruby (instead of the JRuby).

Comment: how can i verify that?

Comment: NB: i'm working on mac os 10.12.5

Comment: Just check if exists these two files in your project folder. It is used by rbenv to manage different ruby versions in different projects. You can find more info about it [here](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects).

Comment: @LucasCosta you linked to `rvm`! He's using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

Comment: @DavidS. yes, I know. But the concepts behind these files are the same :)

Comment: @DavidS & LucasCosta: i'm new to ruby & jruby & i think that my installation and configuration are messed up, is there a proper tutorial that i can follow to redo it from the scratch!! & thank you guys for helping :)

Comment: @IHEB I just posted an answer with some details.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `rbenv`, here are some good troubleshooting steps:

- Ensure that your `PATH` contains `/path/to/your/home/directory/.rbenv/shims` or some similar variant.
- You also need `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in your shell's `.bash|zsh|whateverrc` file.
- If this is all in order, then check the `.ruby-version` file. Change to the directory of the project you're working on and invoke `cat .ruby-version`.

  - If not, just make a new file with this name and place an appropriate JRuby version string in it. A good way to check available versions is `rbenv install --list`, but the latest (from my local `ruby-build`) is `jruby-9.1.7.0`
- Now invoke `rbenv install`. If you don't wish to make the file / want to skip this step just run `rbenv install jruby-9.1.7.0`
- `rbenv rehash; bundle` should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your bundler is trying to use the system's default Ruby version instead of use the JRuby.

I recommend to you uninstall all previous installations of Ruby to make your system clean again.

After that, make sure your `PATH` is correct.
If you're using bash, your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` should have the following commands:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

If you're using zsh, these commands must resides in `~/.zshrc`.

After that, enter your project directory and creates a new file `.ruby-version`:

```
echo 'jruby-9.1.7.0' > .ruby-version
```

**Note:** you can see other versions available using the command `rbenv install --list`.

Lastly, leaves the directory, enter it again, and run the following commands:

```
rbenv install jruby-9.1.7.0
gem install bundler # to install the bundler gem in the context of your new JRuby 9.1.7.0
bundle install      # to install the gems listed in your Gemfile
```

Comment: YES, this is the problem, the bundler is using the system's default Ruby version

Comment: I've uninstalled all previous installations & this time i've build Ruby & Jruby from source

Comment: so now i can't use   export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Comment: Why? What's happening?